# Setting background size in circle on image hover

Tags: html, jquery, css, image, animation

I am making a hover effect on the image. I set the image to grayscale by default and when it hovered over, a circle follows the cursor and shows the colored part. Basically, there are two images. grayscale one is shown by default and on hover inside the circle, the colored part is shown.

[image: check here]

Everything is working good except when I try to size the image using background-size the circle part doesn't follow. As the background property sets the circle part image according to its size. See the code:

I set the background-size of video card to 100% to fill up its parent container but when I do it for the circle, the image is sized inside the circle.

```js
$('.video-card').mousemove(function(e) {

  var offs = $(this).offset(),
    p = {
      x: offs.left,
      y: offs.top
    },
    mPos = {
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
    },
    x = mPos.x - p.x - 75,
    y = mPos.y - p.y - 75;

  $('.gray', this).css({
    left: x,
    top: y,
    backgroundPosition: -x + 'px ' + -y + 'px'
  });

});
```

```css
.video-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 950px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100% !important;
}

.video-card-overlay {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  background-size: 100% !important;
}

.gray {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.video-card:hover>.gray {
  display: block;
}

.video-gallery-section .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="video-card" style="background: url('assets/img/home/1.png') no-repeat">
  <div class="video-card-overlay" style="background: url('assets/img/home/1.png') no-repeat"></div>
  <div class="gray" style="background: url('assets/img/home/1.png') no-repeat"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `clip-path` instead of trying to achieve the same effect through positioning?

```js
const $overlay = $('.video-card-overlay');

$('.video-card').mousemove(function (e) {
    $overlay.css({
        clipPath: `circle(150px at ${e.offsetX}px ${e.offsetY}px)`
    })
});
```

```css
.video-card {
    height: 950px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.gray,
.video-card-overlay {
    background-image: url('assets/img/home/1.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    inset: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.gray {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.video-card:not(:hover) .video-card-overlay {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-card">
    <div class="gray"></div>
    <div class="video-card-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

See how much shorter the code became!

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro. I didn't know about clipPath but you got it working so smoothly. I would definitely learn more about clipPath. Thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Comment: You're welcome! `clip-path` is rather an advanced property. Many people don't know about it. Please upvote and select my answer if it helped :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I wish I could give an upvote but it's saying I am not allowed until 15 reputations.

Comment: Okay, please try now. And you can also select the answer by clicking the tick mark.